# Ul menu wont have float left in container

Tags: html, css

The `<ul>` header isn't starting at the container max-width. I added text over to show where the container is, why isn't the menu also starting there?

https://codepen.io/audn/pen/LLvdGb

```css
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#1f3647;
    width:100%;
    color:#798892;
}
.active{
   background-color: #101d26;
}
li.menu {
    float: left;
}
li.menu a {
    display: block;
    color:#798892 ;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #101d26;
} 
.container{
  max-width:750px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="container">
     nboi
</div>
 <ul class="menu">
   <div class="container">
      <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i></a></li>
      <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE30C;</i></a></li>
      <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE30A;</i></a></li>
      <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE896;</i></a></li>
      <li class="menu" style="float:right;"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0D0;</i></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/zzXWKv

Comment: Yes! explain? @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a `div` as a direct child of a `ul`. Just wrap the menu in an element, apply the `background-color` to that element so the color will be the width of the window, then add `.container` to your `ul` to center it to your viewport width, and add `padding: 0` to remove the default left padding on the `ul`.

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #798892;
  padding: 0;
}
.menuContainer {
  background-color: #1f3647;
}
.active {
  background-color: #101d26;
}
li.menu {
  float: left;
}
li.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #798892;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #101d26;
}
.container {
  max-width: 750px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  nboi
</div>
<div class="menuContainer">
  <ul class="menu container">
    <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i></a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE30C;</i></a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE30A;</i></a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE896;</i></a></li>
    <li class="menu" style="float:right;"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0D0;</i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask another question?

Comment: https://codepen.io/audn/pen/BZEmVv

How can I get the second UL right under the main one?

Comment: Can't see any changes, the <ul class breadcrumb> is not right under the main ul @michaelcoker

Comment: Yea, i want that space between the ul's to be gone

Comment: @hellio oh remove the margins. And pay attention to my solution above. You nested a `div` as a direct child of the `ul` again. Don't do that, it's invalid html. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgGvwa

Comment: What does "nested a div as a direct child" mean, and why is it not good?

Comment: @hellio You can't have `<ul><div></div></ul>` only an `<li>` can be a direct child of a `<ul>`. So it needs to be `<ul><li><div></div></li></ul>`. It's bad because it's invalid HTML. The [ul content model spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) says the only valid content model of a `<ul>` is an `<li>, <script> or <template>`

Answer (score 0):

> Note: it is not allowed put `block` elements inside of `inline` elements as child.

*But other Errors:*

**1)** you limited `.container` to `750px`.remove it:

```
.container {
  max-width:750px;<------------Remove
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

**2)** Insert `padding:0` to `ul.menu` :

```
ul.menu {
 padding:0;
 //more code...
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xjpha2hk/)